# How do I add an item to a dynamic-list, using a button, to another screen with the list?

Tags: arrays, flutter, listview, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm not too familiar with flutter and coding in general yet. I'm also very new here so I apologize for any mistakes I might have done when posting a quesiton. Also, in case it's needed, I use android studio.
 To be more descriptive, I wanna use sharedPreferences to save data taken from 4 Textfields from the 1stScreen as an array and add them to the list on the 2ndScreen. A list that has nothing yet and if the data from the 1st screen is saved, the list then shows 1 item containing the data saved. 
Here's my mess of a code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> litems = List<String>();

  List<String> get Items =>
      this.litems;

  set logList(List<String> value) {
    litems = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with ChangeNotifier {
  TextEditingController firstname = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastname = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController birthday = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController address = TextEditingController();
  //


  String data = "";
  String data1 = "";
  String data2 = "";
  String data3 = "";
  String firstname1 = "f";
  String lastname1 = "l";
  String birthday1 = "";
  String address1 = "";



  Future<bool>saveData() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setString(firstname1, firstname.text);
  }
  Future<bool>saveData1() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences1 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences1.setString(lastname1, lastname.text);
  }
  Future<bool>saveData2() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setString(birthday1, birthday.text);
  }
  Future<bool>saveData3() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences1 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences1.setString(address1, address.text);
  }

///////////

  Future<String> loadData() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getString(firstname1);
  }
  Future<String> loadData1() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences2.getString(lastname1);
  }
  Future<String> loadData2() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getString(birthday1);
  }
  Future<String> loadData3() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences2.getString(address1);
  }


  setData(){
    loadData().then((value){
      setState(() {
        data = value;
      });
    });
  }
  setData1(){
    loadData1().then((value){
      setState(() {
        data1 = value;
      });
    });
  }
  setData2(){
    loadData2().then((value){
      setState(() {
        data2 = value;
      });
    });
  }
  setData3(){
    loadData3().then((value){
      setState(() {
        data3 = value;

      });
    });
  }

  add(screen2){
    screen2.litems.add(data);
    notifyListeners();
    setState(() {

    });
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: firstname,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "FIRST NAME"
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: lastname,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "LAST NAME"
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: birthday,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "BIRTHDAY"
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: address,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "ADDRESS"
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                saveData();
                saveData1();
                saveData2();
                saveData3();
                setData();
                setData1();
                setData2();
                setData3();
                add(screen2());
              },
              child: Text("ADD"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen2()),
                );
              },
              child: Text("SHOW ALL"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

This is the second screen I need to access the list from.

Code snippet taken from [this](https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb)

```
    class screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State createState() => new DyanmicList();
    }

    class DyanmicList extends State<screen2> with ChangeNotifier {
      List<String> litems = [];




      final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();
      @override
      Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Screen2"),),
            body: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                  controller: eCtrl,
                  onSubmitted: (text) {
                    litems.add(text);
                    eCtrl.clear();
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                new Expanded(
                    child: new ListView.builder
                      (
                        itemCount: litems.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                          return new Text(litems[Index]);
                        }
                    )
                )
              ],
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also, should I clean up that Provider code? Or will everything be shorter if I used it?

Comment: I would suggest you store the 4 data in a list and store to `sharedPreferences` .Then in second page retrieve the list from `sharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @JohnJoe! Alright, so I'll do that but is it possible to have just one function to store all 4 data? And if you don't mind me asking a simple question, does this mean that I'll have 1 list for storing the 4 data in the 1stScreen and another list in the 2ndScreen for displaying the data I received from the 1stScreen?

Comment: exactly. I provided my answer below, hope it make sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In screen 1,when submit button is pressed, add the 4 info into a list and store to `sharedPreferences`.

**Screen1**

```
var list = List<Info>();
        ...
list.add(Info(firstName,lastName,birthday,address));
prefs.storeList(json.encode(list));
```

**Info**

```
class Info {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String birthday;
  String address;

  Info(this.firstName, this.lastName,this.birthday,this.address);
}
```

**SharedPreferences**

```
     Future storeList(String info) async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString(INFO, info);
      }
    
   Future getListFromSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString(INFO);
  }
```

**Screen 2**

In screen 2 widget build, use `FutureBuilder` to get the list from `sharedPreferences`.

```
 FutureBuilder(
        future: sharedPreferences.getListFromSharedPreferences(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (jsonDecode(snapshot.data)).length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                  return new Text(jsonDecode(snapshot.data)[index]);
                });
          } else {
            return Text("No data");
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks again! I'll try this and the other answer out and will update later!

Comment: Alright, so in -----list.add(Info(firstname,lastname,birthday,address));------, "Info" has an error saying "The method 'Info' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'. ". 
Also, in ----prefs.storeList(json.encode(list));----, it also says "The method 'storeList' isn't defined for the type 'SharedPreferences'."
I might have did something wrong but I've put this into a function to call upon clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use SharedPreferences for saving `List` of `String`, you can use `setStringList()` rather than `setString()` You can do achieve this by following way.

On your first screen,

```
RaisedButton(
      onPressed: (){
         List<String> _userData = [];
        _userData.add(firstname.text);
        _userData.add(lastname.text);
        _userData.add(birthday.text);
        _userData.add(address.text);
               
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        myPrefs.setStringList("user", _userData);
              },
       child: Text("ADD"),
```

Then On Second Screen

```
class screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State createState() => new DyanmicList();
    }

    class DyanmicList extends State<screen2> {
      List<String> litems = [];



   @override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser();
   }

getUser() async{
SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var userData=  myPrefs.getStringList("user");
setState((){
litems = userData;
});
}

      final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();
      @override
      Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Screen2"),),
            body: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                  controller: eCtrl,
                  onSubmitted: (text) {
                    litems.add(text);
                    eCtrl.clear();
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                new Expanded(
                    child: new ListView.builder
                      (
                        itemCount: litems.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                          return new Text(litems[Index]);
                        }
                    )
                )
              ],
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, @Ranjit! I'll try this and the other answer out and will update later!

Comment: This works! Thank you. And if you don't mind me asking another.. Whenever I would go back to the 1stScreen to add more data to the 2ndScreen, the previous data I entered had been erased and is replaced with the new data. How do I prevent the data from being erased?